# Logging module ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console'

Tags: python, logging, web-crawler

I was trying to figure out how to do web scraping/crawling with Python, so I downloaded a crawler I found on GitHub to see how it worked, it's called PyCrawler and the code is [here](https://github.com/theanti9/PyCrawler). When I try to execute it, I get the folowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyCrawler.py", line 18, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 803, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 585, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': must be string, not None
```

There's no `None` value in the `console` dictionary, so I suppose it gives the error because for some reason it can't read it properly, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `ColorStreamHandler.py` in your folder (or available on Python's path)? notice that 'console' is instantiated as a `ColorStreamHandler`.

```
'console': {
            'class': 'ColorStreamHandler.ColorStreamHandler',
            ...
        } ...
```

Add `ColorStreamHandler` to your folder and it should work.

Comment: The file is already in the script's directory. I downloaded the source and left it as it was.

Comment: I found the problem: it was actually with the ColorStreamHandle module, but it was because it uses the curses module, which doesn't work on Windows.